# Laravel 5.5: Convert multidimensional array to single one

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.5

I want to convert following multidimensional array to single one. And ***only*** `parent_id` column of children array should be the same as `category_id` of parent array. And `sort_order_number` of children array should be equal to their position in *children* array.  And `sort_order_number` of parent array should be the equal to their position in *parent* array:

***Current multidimensional array***:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:12 [▼
    "text_az" => "title1"
    "text_en" => "title1.1"
    "text_ru" => "title1.2"
    "slug" => "sfsf"
    "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
    "target" => "_top"
    "id" => 1
    "sort_order_number" => 1
    "parent_id" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "children" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:12 [▼
        "text_az" => "title3"
        "text_en" => "title3.1"
        "text_ru" => "title3.2"
        "slug" => "sdf"
        "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
        "target" => "_top"
        "id" => 3
        "sort_order_number" => 1
        "parent_id" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "children" => array:1 [▼
          0 => array:11 [▼
            "text_az" => "title2"
            "text_en" => "title2.1"
            "text_ru" => "title2.2"
            "slug" => "fsdfsf"
            "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
            "target" => "_top"
            "id" => 2
            "sort_order_number" => 2
            "parent_id" => null
            "created_at" => null
            "updated_at" => null
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:11 [▼
    "text_az" => "title4"
    "text_en" => "title4.1"
    "text_ru" => "title4.2"
    "slug" => "treteterter"
    "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
    "target" => "_top"
    "id" => 4
    "sort_order_number" => 2
    "parent_id" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
]
```

***Single dimensional array that I would love to have after conversion:***

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:12 [▼
    "text_az" => "title1"
    "text_en" => "title1.1"
    "text_ru" => "title1.2"
    "slug" => "sfsf"
    "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
    "target" => "_top"
    "id" => 1
    "sort_order_number" => 1
    "parent_id" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
  1 => array:12 [▼
    "text_az" => "title3"
    "text_en" => "title3.1"
    "text_ru" => "title3.2"
    "slug" => "sdf"
    "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
    "target" => "_top"
    "id" => 3
    "sort_order_number" => 1
    "parent_id" => 1
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null

  ]
  2 => array:12 [▼
    "text_az" => "title2"
    "text_en" => "title2.1"
    "text_ru" => "title2.2"
    "slug" => "fsdfsf"
    "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
    "target" => "_top"
    "id" => 2
    "sort_order_number" => 2
    "parent_id" => 3
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null

  ]
  3 => array:12 [▼
    "text_az" => "title4"
    "text_en" => "title4.1"
    "text_ru" => "title4.2"
    "slug" => "treteterter"
    "icon" => "fa fa-bell"
    "target" => "_top"
    "id" => 4
    "sort_order_number" => 2
    "parent_id" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null

  ]

]
```

Comment: i assume you tried something to come up with your desired structure, post the code here

Comment: Use recursion, check if the current key is an array, if it is, then add it to a new array.

Comment: Can you show me how I can do that based on my explanation? I need code sample in php. I tried many ways but none of them worked for me. (

Answer (score 2):

As you array is in a fixed structure, you can do it like this, a **[simple demo](https://eval.in/903278)**

```
$result = [];
$count = 1;
$temp = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use(&$result, &$count, &$temp) {
    $temp[$k] = $v;
    if($count++ % 11 == 0) {
        $temp["sort_order_number"] = intval($count / 11);
        $result[] = $temp;
        $temp = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: It gave me just empty array result(

Comment: I've edited my answer by `&$result` instead of `$result`

Comment: Thanks Kris it worked. But what about sort_order_number? How can I fix it?

Comment: Kris, sorry. Last issue: How can I fix `parent_id` problem?